# Calculating residue of a line integral

Tags: residue-calculus, line-integrals

My book has a confusing residue calculation:

$$\int_c \frac{4-3z}{z^2-z}dz$$

$$\int_c \frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}dz$$

So when evaluating the residue at z = 0
$$Res_{z=0} [ \frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}]$$

I don't understand how subbing z=0 gives us this? Shouldn't the denominator just be 0 since when z=0 the whole denom = 0?

$$= [\frac{4-3z}{z-1}]_{z=0} = -4$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\operatorname{res}_{z=a}f(z)$ means “residue of $f$ at $a$”. So, $\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}$ stands for the residue of $\frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}$ at $0$ (which is indeed $-4$).

Comment: But when z= 0, isn't the denom = 0?

Comment: Sure. And it's because of that that $0$ is a singularity of $\frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}$.

Comment: But when z=0, how do we get -4 if the denom is 0?. Perhaps I have just forgotten how limits work.

Comment: Whenever $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)$ exists, we have $\operatorname{res}_{z=a}f(z)=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)$, and therefore$$\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}=\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{4-3z}{z(z-1)}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{4-3z}{z-1}=-4.$$